# How to validate a non required filed with yup

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I'm using yup with formik for validations. I want to validate a non-required field with yup. Here test is a non-required field but when user enters we are blocking him to enter some special characters. when the user didn't enter anything then also it is validating( i don't need this validation until user enters something). Can anyone help me, Thanks in advance

```
   const validationSchema = function (values) {
    return Yup.object().shape({
       test: Yup.string()
      .matches(/^[^<&>`#]+$/,'test should not contain `, &, #, <, > \n')
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The combination of `errors.yourFieldName` and `touched.yourFieldName` solves your problem:

So if the name of your input field is `test` to show/hide errors :

```
{errors.test && touched.test ? {errors.test}: 'Valid form'}
```

and to enable/disable your submit button:

```
<button disabled={touched.test && (!isValid || isSubmitting)}>
```

I created a simple demo to illustrate this here https://codesandbox.io/s/q8vz32mpw

Comment: Hi @Ala Eddine JEBALI, Thanks for the response. I just tried your steps in the field array validations still am getting the same error( may be am missing something). I created a demo to illustrate my issue https://codesandbox.io/s/6x3yj3kjlw

Comment: This is because you declared `founded_by` as an array in `const Values = { founded_by: [], }` but you are validating it as a string with Yup `founded_by: Yup.string().matches(...)`

Comment: So for that field you should change it like this: `const Values = { founded_by: "", founders: ... }`

Comment: what about founders?

Comment: This is not related to your question because you marked them as `required`: `<Input type="text" name={\`founders[${index}].linkedinLink\`}  required ... />`

Comment: if founders also non-required filed then how we can achieve this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188666/discussion-between-abhiram-and-ala-eddine-jebali).